# Entity Framework code first Fluent mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables

- StoreOrderItem
- StoreOrder

Now StoreOrder has many StoreOrderItems and StoreOrderItem has one StoreOrder (simple 1 to many relationship)

```
public class StoreOrderItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<StoreOrderItem>
{
        public StoreOrderItemMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("StoreOrderItem");
            this.HasKey(op => op.Id);
            this.Property(op => op.StoreOrderId).HasColumnName("order_id");
            ...

            this.HasRequired(so => so.StoreOrder)
              .WithMany(soi => soi.StoreOrderItems)
              .HasForeignKey(so => so.StoreOrderId);
        }
}

public class StoreOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<StoreOrder>
{
    public StoreOrderMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("StoreOrder");
        this.HasKey(op => op.Id);
        ....
    }
}

public class StoreOrderItem
{
    ....
    public virtual int StoreOrderId { get; set; }
    ....

    public virtual StoreOrder StoreOrder { get; set; }
}

public class StoreOrder
{
    .... 
    private ICollection<StoreOrderItem> _storeOrderItems;
    ....

    public virtual ICollection<StoreOrderItem> StoreOrderItems
    {
        get { return _storeOrderItems ?? (_storeOrderItems = new List<StoreOrderItem>()); }
        set { _storeOrderItems = value; }
    }

}

//The code which is used to add the configurations to the modelBuilder.
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    System.Type configType = typeof(ContentMap);   //any of your configuration classes here
    var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(configType).GetTypes()
        .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
        .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Note I am running this code on an existing DB, how do I tell EF to not select "StoreOrder_Id" and to instead use the existing column "order_id"?

Here is the error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid column name 'StoreOrder_Id'.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column
>   name 'StoreOrder_Id'.

Comment: Are you sure that your map is used in mapping?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: I ask if you have added `StoreOrderItemMap` to `DbModelBuilder`'s `Configurations` collection when building your model?

Comment: In your DbContext class did you have method protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)?

Comment: Yes this is being done for every typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration) using reflection

Comment: @Paul: can you show a code fragment, which adds entity configurations to model builder?

Comment: I have updated my original post :)

Comment: @Paul: have looked into `modelBuilder.Configurations` after `foreach` loop? Are there all types you need?

Comment: Perhaps the Id column of `StoreOrder` should be mapped to "order_id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem after a few days of mind bending ......

There was another property in the StoreOrder class

```
public virtual IList<StoreOrderItem> NonVoucherOrderItems
{
    get
    {
        return this.StoreOrderItems.Where(x => !x.IsVoucher()).ToList();
    }
}
```

This was being evaluated too early and causing all sorts of chaos, changed to

```
public virtual IEnumerable<StoreOrderItem> NonVoucherOrderItems
{
    get
    {
        return this.StoreOrderItems.Where(x => !x.IsVoucher());
    }
}
```

And it worked immediately!!